# request getparameter radio button al refrescarse

Tags: java, jsp, radiobutton

Disculpen, estoy haciendo un método con `request.getParameter("objeto");` donde al refrescarse un `form` con `input` `submit` estoy haciendo que las respuestas de los input text que uno mismo escribe pues se queden en su lugar y no desaparezcan no se borren pues, pero resulta que con input `radio` no he podido lograr el mismo resultado, de hecho lo intenté igual así

```
<%
String obj = request.getParameter("objeto");

if(obj==null){
%>
<input type="radio" name="radios" value="Si" />
<input type="radio" name="radios" value="No" />
<%
} else {
%>
<input type="radio" name="radios" value="<%=obj%>" />
<input type="radio" name="radios" value="<%=obj%>" />
<%
}
%>
```

Y la verdad es que no me resultó, el radio button no se quedó marcado. Si saben algo de si de casualidad por ahi no es el camino, háganmelo saber por favor, entonces que método podría ser el correcto, algo por el estilo, por su atención muchas gracias, feliz jueves

Comment: entiendo que quieres mantener el estado de un radio button, cuando vuelves a un formulario, para ello primero deberías conocer su estado actual, almacenarlo y luego recuperarlo. He entendido que los radio buttonn son diferentes a los demás objetos a los que haces mención es por eso, que imagino no logras capturar su valor al estar seleccionado, y es que los radio button , tienen una propiedad de tipo checked, la misma puede ser true/false, dependiendo del valor seleccionado o no.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: pues lo declare que if(bpro=="Si") el checked lo llevaba el input radio "Si" y si else pues seria igual a input radio "No", lo curioso es que cuando marco el "Si", en vez de refrescarse en "Si", me refresca en "No" y ya lo intenté también con if(bpro==null) y los otros dos resultados y nada, o me sale el ultimo resultado o cuando si usar el else y con los if quiero declarar bpro=="Si" o bpro=="No" pues ni siquiera me devuelve los input radio si no que me parece vacio, o sea, no 3esta funcionando tu consejo, no le faltara algo mas por ahi?

Comment: pues al final la respuesta la encontre aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249114/how-to-use-if-else-in-scriplets-in-jsp-as-a-condition-to-show-radio-button-value, de todos modos gracias